# SQL Query School Course pre Requisite

Tags: sql

Scripts:
Build Schema script provided. 
for each student ,  need to print if he missed any pre-requisites, plus the current application course from the application table . it should not print any course already registered in register table. . Expected result given inside the script.

```
create table applications ( student_id INT, requested_course VARCHAR(4) ) ;
INSERT INTO applications ( student_id, requested_course )
values ( 1,'ML'),(2,'CMP'),(3,'ML');

CREATE TABLE register
(student_id int, registered varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO register
(student_id, registered)
VALUES
(1, 'HS'),
(1, 'PHY'),
(1, 'CMP'),
(2, 'MTH')
;

CREATE TABLE prerequisites
(course VARCHAR(4),prerequisite_course VARCHAR(4))
;

INSERT INTO prerequisites
(course, prerequisite_course)
VALUES
('MTH', 'HS'),
('PHY', 'HS'),
('CHM', 'HS'),
('CMP', 'MTH'),
('ML', 'CMP'),
('AP', 'CMP')
;
```

Final Query ( My try) - not working.

```
Select rq.student_id, rq.requested_course as course from applications rq
Where not exists ( select 1 from register rg where
rg.student_id=rq.student_id and rg.registered=rq.requested_course)

Union

Select rq.student_id,st.prerequisite_course as course from applications rq
Join prerequisites st ON st.course=rq.requested_course
Where not exists ( select 1 from register rg where
rg.student_id=rq.student_id and rg.registered=rq.requested_course
and st.prerequisite_course=rg.registered )
order by student_id
;
```

Expected result

```
Student_id Course
-----------------
  1.    'MTH'
  1     'ML'
  2     'HS'
  2     'CMP'
  3     'HS'
  3     'MTH'
  3     'CMP'
  3     'ML'
```

for student ID 1 : he is opting for ML.So it will be included. He already registered for CMP.So CMP excluded. Now he did not do pre-req MTH . So final result : MTH and ML

for Student ID 2: he is opting for CMP. One of the pre-req MTH is in register table, HS is not. So expected result: CMP, HS.

for student ID 3: Opting for ML.So ML included.no pre-reqs are in registered table. So for 3, expected result HS, MTH, CMP,  ML.

Comment: "Not working" means what? We need to know what it's doing.

Comment: Not working means not getting expected result.  for each student , i  need to get if he missed any pre-requisites, plus the current application course . it should not print any  course already registered.

Comment: You need to show us what you're getting so we've got a better sense of where things are going wrong. That's a lot of SQL code to try and work through without any idea of where it's already at.

Comment: @byomjan . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and Insert Table Scripts

```
create table #applications ( student_id INT, requested_course VARCHAR(4) ) ;
INSERT INTO #applications ( student_id, requested_course )
values ( 1,'ML'),(2,'CMP'),(3,'ML');

CREATE TABLE #register
(student_id int, registered varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO #register
(student_id, registered)
VALUES
(1, 'HS'),
(1, 'PHY'),
(1, 'CMP'),
(2, 'MTH')
;

CREATE TABLE #prerequisites
(course VARCHAR(4),prerequisite_course VARCHAR(4))
;

INSERT INTO #prerequisites
(course, prerequisite_course)
VALUES
('MTH', 'HS'),
('PHY', 'HS'),
('CHM', 'HS'),
('CMP', 'MTH'),
('ML', 'CMP'),
('AP', 'CMP')
;
```

Logic Using while loop and recursive CTE

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') is not null)
    drop table #temp

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#results') is not null)
    drop table #results

    If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pre') is not null)
    drop table #pre

create table #results
(
Student_id int, course varchar(20)
)
create table #pre
(
course varchar(10),
prerequisite_course varchar(10)
)


Declare @count int,@startcount int=1,@studentid int

select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by student_id asc) as RN,* into #temp from #applications
select @count=count(*) from #temp



while(@startcount<=@count)
begin
set @studentid= (select student_id from #temp where RN=@startcount)


;with cte1 as
(
select * from #prerequisites where course=(select top 1 b.prerequisite_course from 
#applications a
join #prerequisites b on a.requested_course=b.course
where student_id=@studentid)
UNION ALL
select b.prerequisite_course,b.course from #prerequisites b
join cte1 on cte1.course=b.course
)
insert into #pre
select * from cte1

insert into #results
select * from #applications where student_id=@studentid
union 
select ISNULL(a.student_id,@studentid),#pre.prerequisite_course
from 
#pre
left join #register a on a.registered=#pre.prerequisite_course and a.student_id=@studentid
where a.student_id is null 
set @startcount=@startcount+1
end
select * from #results
```

Output

```
Student_id  course
1   ML
1   MTH
2   CMP
2   HS
3   CMP
3   HS
3   ML
3   MTH
```